# GROUP BY doesn't work on ticket

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an error with this queries that says  :

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Column 'CrmDesk.Ticket.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

This is my query:

```
Select * 
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where TicketCode in (select DISTINCT(TicketCode) 
                     from CrmDesk.Ticket 
                     where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B')
group by TicketCode
```

This query has the same error

```
select * 
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
group by TicketCode
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Read about how `Group By` works. Or alteast say what are you trying to acheive

Comment: Only columns that are in the group by clause can also be in the select clause without an aggregate function. If you have the same ticket code for multiple id values, what id value would you like to get back?

Comment: its not important what id values of ticket code get back all records with same ticket code have same Subject And Comment field In fact I Need Subject , Comment And Ticket Code

Comment: You need to group by only if you are aggregating the columns. In this case you are selecting all the columns. If you could provide how your final result should look like, will be very much useful to help you

Answer (score 0):

You should include the columns in the group by clause which is in the select list.

If you wanted to check the same ticket with same subject and comment, use the below script..

```
  Select *
  From crmdesk.ticket t
    Join ( select t1.ticketcode,t1.subject,t1.comment
               From crmdesk.ticket t1
               Group by t1.ticketcode,t1.subject,t1.comment
               Having count(t1.id) >1) t1-- assuming you have an ID column, if not replace with ticketcode or any other relevant column 
             On t.ticketcode=t1.ticketcode
                  And t.subject=t1.subject
                  And t.comment=t1.comment
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need a sub query and `GROUP BY` clause in this select statement??
For just select statement you can use the following query:

```
select * 
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where TicketCode  
where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'
```

Answer (score 0):

You must determine why you need grouping by ticketcode?

If you want to get just distinct ticket codes values:

```
Select TicketCode
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'
group by TicketCode
```

If you want to count something:

```
Select TicketCode, COUNT(ID)
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'
group by TicketCode
```

If you want just distinct values (without duplicates):

```
Select distinct Subject, Comment, TicketCode
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'
```

Or:

```
Select Subject, Comment, TicketCode
from CrmDesk.Ticket 
where ReciverUserId ='3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'
group by Subject, Comment, TicketCode
```

Comment: i want get records group by only by "TicketCode" . 
In Fact i want a record(its not important what record ) where ReciverUserId  = '3A4AA2F4-75C8-4725-8F16-81F34158258B'

Comment: Please, show what you have now, and what you want to get. Data samples. Group by will do grouping for column you determine, but other columns must be in aggregate functions such as max, min, avg.

Comment: Maybe you want top 1 for every ticket?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `group by` in your query, you must use one of aggreagte functions such as: `sum`, `min` , `max`, `count`, ...